# Problems with aligning contents grid-wise using float

Tags: html, css

Look at this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZCXn.png

I'm using 'float:left' to align contents of my website grid-wise.

On the left side, the space between the two objects is 24px, whereas on the right side it's 10px. It is happening automatically because of using float. I don't want the spaces to be different on both sides if the boxes are of different heights. I want the alignment to be like facebook timeline.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use something like Masonry: http://masonry.desandro.com/. HTML/CSS can't do it by itself.

Comment: Masonry is great. There is Isotope as well: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html

Comment: How to use it? I don't understand.